# Reuse StatefulKnowledgeSession in multiple executions

Tags: java, drools

I have a problem when try to execute twice in one statefulKnowlegdeSession in drools:

```
final KnowledgeBase kbase = knowledgeAgent.getKnowledgeBase();
final StatefulKnowledgeSession session = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
session.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("Third").setFocus();
session.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("Second").setFocus();
session.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("First").setFocus();
session.execute(CommandFactory.newBatchExecution(commands));
//This execution doesn't work:
session.execute(CommandFactory.newBatchExecution(anothersCommands));
session.dispose();
```

The second execution never happen, what is bad? can I reuse drools session in multiple execution?

I'm using drools 5.6.0.Final

Regards

Comment: One would have to see the commands (including inserted facts) and the rules to learn why there aren't any results from the second execute. - But I can tell you right away that the three setFocus calls don't make sense being called one after the other: only the last agenda group is active for both command executions.